# How to automatically add Sequelize columns from model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to know how to force Sequelize to automatically add new columns to the database if added in the model. Currently, I'm required to log into the MySQL server and add the columns manually. I understand that there is a way to automatically drop and rebuild the tables, however I would like to preserve the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the automatic way (using sync({ force: true })) drops all data before rebuilding the tables.
The way to modify the database scheme without losing data is to use *migrations* as explained in the doc here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/
Basically, you can programmatically describe the updates you want to make to your model via methods such as *createTable*, *addColumn*, *changeColumn*, ...
The migration scripts can be executed using the Sequelize CLI.